# How can I make date columns much more attractive for data exploration in postgres instead of Python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a graph of stock market data, made using Plotly-Dash. I plot x for dates, y for price. When plotting x-data as dates, the labels are always wonky and weird for data exploration.

For example:
[image]

As you can see, the x axis is a series of Jan and Jul months throughout the years. This is naturally auto generated and doesn't look nice for a user-experience. It would be much better having Q1 2015, Q2 2015, or Winter 2016, Summer 2016, etc...

In Python I can do that by editing a dataframe similarly like this:

```
for column in lst:
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 1, "month"] = "January"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 2, "month"] = "February"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 3, "month"] = "March"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 4, "month"] = "April"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 5, "month"] = "May"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 6, "month"] = "June"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 7, "month"] = "July"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 8, "month"] = "August"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 9, "month"] = "September"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 10, "month"] = "October"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 11, "month"] = "November"
    column.loc[column["month_int"] == 12, "month"] = "December"
    
# Or like this     

for column in lst2:
    column.loc[(column['month_int'] > 2) & (column['month_int'] <= 5), 'Season'] = 'Spring'
    column.loc[(column['month_int'] > 5) & (column['month_int'] <= 8), 'Season'] = 'Summer'
    column.loc[(column['month_int'] > 8) & (column['month_int'] <= 11), 'Season'] = 'Autumn'
    column.loc[column['month_int'] <= 2, 'Season'] = 'Winter'
    column.loc[column['month_int'] == 12, 'Season'] = 'Winter
```

What is the equivalent of this but for Postgres? I'm trying to learn more SQL tricks and replace unnecessary python code. For reference, here is my query

```
SELECT symbol, date, adj_close 
FROM api.security_price 
WHERE security_price.symbol IN %s AND date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM api.security_price) - interval '5 years' 
ORDER by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the month, you can use the `TO_CHAR` function  in postgres.

```
select symbol, date, to_char(date, 'Month') as month, adj_close from api.security_price 
WHERE security_price.symbol IN %s AND date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM api.security_price) - interval '5 years' 
ORDER by date;
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

Similarly, you can also define your own sql query functions for special cases.
Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html.

For season, another simple way to do this would be to have another column containing a month_int to season mapping and doing a left join with that  table on your output data.

Comment: Is there a notable reason why adding your new addition threw off my query? I'm getting a weird value for my years?

Comment: try putting all references to `date` in double quotes. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: We cannot see weird! Please post the resulting query and the results it produced.